# Using a usb-c laptop charger to charge a phone

Tags: telephone, laptop, usb-c

I don't really know anything about electronics and I'm not sure if it's the right place to ask, but still.

Is it OK to charge my phone with my laptop's charger?

Here's info on the laptop charger:
[image]

And here's info on the phone charger:
[image]

Comment: USB-C negotiates voltage - your phone seems to only support the 5V charger option, your laptop charge also supports 5V charge option. All is good, you'll be fine using it. In any case the question is off-topic - EE.SE is about electronic *design*, not *use*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the fact that both devices do have the Type-C connector doesn't mean that both devices will be interchangeable to full functional capacity. The Type-C specifies connector and its use for USB connectivity, with basic provisions do discriminate few power supply options at 5-V level. The connector can use any other means to communicate with chargers on the top (or instead) of basic functionality.

To begin, your laptop charger (Xiaomi?) supports some sort of "fast charging" capability and lists several "power profiles". However, it is not clear whether it does it over standard Power Delivery Specifications, or via Qualcomm QuickCharge proprietary specifications. Still looks more like a PD.

Your Sony charger seems to support either basic Type-C 5V1.5A profile, or it might use Sony proprietary signature over USB 2.0 lines. Again it is not clear.

Bottom line is that it might charge your Sony with full blast (5V1.5A), or the phone might resort to basic 5V 900 mA (or even 500 mA) charging if it uses Sony proprietary charger signature.

In both cases you can safely plug it in and see if the phone gets charged fast enough.